# Django template question: how to output just the text if the variable has html in it?

Tags: python, django

I have a lot of variables that has html in them. For example the value of a variable called {{object.name}} is the following:

```
Play this <a href="#">hot</a> game and see how <b>fun</b> it is!
```

Is there a filter that can be applied on the variable that will give me just the text:

```
Play this hot game and see how fun it is!
```

*Without* the text being linked or the html being replaced by htmlentities. Just the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[striptags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#striptags) filter removes all html

{{object.name|striptags}}

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options to strip the html code:

Using "[safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)" filter in your template:

```
{{ object.name|safe }}
```

Using "[autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#autoescape)" tag in your template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ object.name }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

or declaring it as "[safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)" in your python code:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
name = mark_safe(name)
```